# Firefly scenes with Han Solo in the background

Tags: firefly, han-solo

Apparently there are many scenes in *Firefly* where a figurine of Han Solo frozen in carbonite appears in the background.

Is there a complete list of all of these scenes?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Shiny! I hadn't heard about this before.

It appears that the canonical list is [in this blog post](http://geekfemme.blogspot.com/2011/01/han-solos-in-firefly.html). So far, it's been found in:

- "Heart of Gold"
- "Jaynestown"
- "Objects in Space"
- "The Message"
- "Serenity"
- "Our Mrs Reynolds"
- "Out of Gas"

There's more discussion about this [on io9](http://io9.com/5730997/can-you-spot-all-of-the-han-solo-appearances-on-firefly).

Comment: This answer could be improved with pictures.